# Way for Teams App to have dynamic bot configuration

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am building a Teams App with Bot functionality for proactive messaging targeting single tenants, however I would like to have the bot published in the public marketplace so that users can install it from the marketplace instead of sideloading to their teams. The bot resources and code will be dynamically created on the tenant's azure.

Is there a way for me to have the bot id on the marketplace be dynamic depending on who installed it?

Comment: By default the bot is multitenant application. You can use the same bot Id across different tenants.

Comment: Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved or still looking for any help?

Answer (score 0):

By default the bot is multitenant application. You can use the same bot Id across different tenants.